# Postgres .NET core 3.1 web api, npgsql, cannot use POST method

Tags: postgresql, postman

I'm running into a problem. I have .net core 3.1 web api that can successfully use GET method to fetch participant table data from a postgres localhost, but I cannot use POST method. Postman throws error ""Parameter '@FirstName' must have its value set"", despite giving it non null input. I'm not sure if the problem is I don't use postman properly or the C# code is wrong. I'm a newbie in .NET core 3.1 so any help is more than welcome.

[image: Postman Post error screenshot]

Participant table:

```sql
-- Table: public.Participant

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public."Participant";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public."Participant"
(
    "Id" integer NOT NULL,
    "First Name" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Last Name" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "Date Of Birth" date,
    "Sex" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "Participant_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("First Name", "Last Name"),
    CONSTRAINT "Id" UNIQUE ("Id")
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public."Participant"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Post Method:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Npgsql;
using Assignment.Models;
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace Assignment.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ParticipantController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        public ParticipantController(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _env = env;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Get()
        {
            string query = @"
                select * from ""Participant""
            ";

            try
            {
                //create datatable and configuration stirng
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ParticipantConnectionString");

                //initialize npgsql reader
                NpgsqlDataReader myReader;
                using (NpgsqlConnection myCon = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
                {
                    myCon.Open();

                    //create command from given query and connection
                    using (NpgsqlCommand myCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, myCon))
                    {
                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);

                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();

                    }
                }

                return new JsonResult(table);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new JsonResult(e);
            }
            
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Post(Participant participant)
        {
            string query = @"
                insert into ""Participant"" 
                (""Id"", ""First Name"", ""Last Name"", ""Date Of Birth"", ""Sex"")
                values (@Id,@FirstName,@LastName,@DateOfBirth,@Sex) 
            ";

            //create datatable and configuration stirng
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("ParticipantConnectionString");

            //initialize npgsql reader
            NpgsqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                using (NpgsqlConnection myCon = new NpgsqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
                {
                    myCon.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlCommand myCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(query, myCon))
                    {

                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", participant.Id);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", participant.FirstName);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", participant.LastName);
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", Convert.ToDateTime(participant.DateOfBirth));
                        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", participant.Sex);

                        //myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoFileName", participant.PhotoFileName);

                        myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        table.Load(myReader);

                        myReader.Close();
                        myCon.Close();

                    }
                }

                return new JsonResult("Added Successfully");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return new JsonResult(e);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Participant class:

```cs
public class Participant
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `"First Name"` (with a space) but your model contains `"FirstName"` (with no space)

You can either modify what you post (remove the space), or instruct your model to accept bindings to a parameter containing a space (see the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0))

```cs
[FromQuery(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Comment: I removed the space from the table and it worked, thank you! How would you change the code with the other approach? There isn't any info on the docs about spaces. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @MichaelEfraimidis see edits, you must use the `name` property to the new name